# Listing all users and their personal site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, client-object-model, mysite

I would like to get a list of all users and their personal sites (mysites). (This is supposed to run on SharePoint Online from an app or a timer job.) I have tried all day but I can't get past the first step: i.e. to get all users in the tenancy. Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using Search REST API for this. The API can be used to query User Profiles and return the path to their My Site. You could even create a A-Z directory if you wanted. Very easy to do with search.

Answer (score -2):

The following technet artcile should help -
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911464.aspx

Comment: Provide brief explanation of answer along with reference link to allow other users to understand the answer rather than opening the link each time.