# How to get personal site of a sharepoint user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

I want to find all the personal sites. I am following the first answer of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/listing-all-users-and-their-personal-site-in-sharepoint-online) question. I got list of all users using `https://abc.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers` API but I am not sure how to get personal site given the user. I want to use API and not powershell

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below powershell cmdlet to get all the personal sites:

```
Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit all -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" | Select -ExpandProperty Url
```

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/list-onedrive-urls

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is not useful for me because I want to use API and not powershell

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online -You login Select your photo in the Microsoft 365 header and then select My Office profile then you can get the personal site of a SharePoint user.

Ref:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-and-collaborate-in-office-delve-46f92806-b52c-4187-b60e-b3bf8d25f73e